# Print ArrayList data to ASP.NET page using GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Trying to print the stored data of arraylist to the gridview.

.aspx File, Working perfectly fine.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Stock Management System</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:#63AA9C;
            text-align:center
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table align="center" border="0" style="background-color:lightcoral">
        <tr><td>Item Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="Name" placeholder="Item Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Quantity:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="Quan"  placeholder="Quantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="Pri" placeholder="Price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="Desc" placeholder="Descrition" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td><asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Store Data" OnClientClick="Store()" width="200px"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><asp:Button ID="Show" runat="server" Text="Show Data" OnClientClick="Print()" width="200px" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Remove Last Added Data" OnClientClick="Remove()" width="200px" /></td></tr>
        </table>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral" ></asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral" ></asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral"></asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs File

No error, but not working while pressing the `show data` button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList price = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList quantity = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList description = new ArrayList();
        static int a = 0;
        protected GridView GridView1;
        protected GridView GridView2;
        protected GridView GridView3;
        protected GridView GridView4;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    public void Store()
    {
        items.Add(Name.Text);
        price.Add(Pri.Text);
        quantity.Add(Quan.Text);
        description.Add(Desc.Text);
        a++;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = items;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataSource = quantity;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        GridView3.DataSource = price;
        GridView3.DataBind();
        GridView4.DataSource = description;
        GridView4.DataBind();

    }

    public void Remove()
    {
        if (a > 0)
        {
            items.RemoveAt(a);
            a--;
        }
    }
}
}
```

My page, Trying to show stored data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

About the attribute OnClientClick you are using, [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx) says

> Gets or sets the client-side script that executes when a Button control's Click event is raised.

which means you are trying to execute a JavaScript function called "Print" in your code (same goes with other buttons).
You should check Button.Click event instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx